# reading multiple xml attributes on xml child nodes jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Hi guys I'm trying to parse an xml document using jquery but i keep hitting a limitation or so i think. When a node has muliple child nodes i only get the first node. let me show an example.

```
  <sheetData>
   <row r="1" spans="1:2" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
    <c r="A1" t="s">
    <v>0</v>
    </c>
     <c r="B1" t="s">
   <v>1</v>
 </c>
```

i use the following code to try to parse this data but it only get the first attribute i dont know what im doing wrong . here is the code.

```
       $(xml).find("row").each(function(i) {
        v1 =  $(this).find("c").attr("r");
```

i should end up with A1 and B1 but im only getting the A1. Any ideas suggestion I would be forever greatful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attr` method will only get the attribute value of the first element from the matched set of elements. If you want it for all elements then use `each` or some other loop and get the attribute value from each element. Try this.

```
  $(xml).find("row").each(function(i) {
      var attrs = [];
      v1 =  $(this).find("c").each(function(){
          attrs.push($(this).attr("r"));
      });

      //Now attrs will contain both A1 and B1 attribute values.
  });
```

Comment: thank you my good man that was genius I pretty new to jquery. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

No, [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

**Description**: Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements.

You match 2 `<c>` but then .attr() returns exactly what it is supposed to.